# Salt generation for stream cypher

Tags: openssl, salt

Sorry if this is an elementary question but I could not find a direct answer.

For end-to-end encryption of messages that wait temporarily on a server and where the sizes can vary from just a few characters to a much larger amount of characters.

It seems like OpenSSL AES-ctr would be a reasonable choice, but I'm not sure about the implications of the salt.

If the pass phrase is static, does the fact that there are potentially many messages for the same user mean that the salt should be randomized per message?

If so, is OpenSSL rand a good enough way to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking: yes, it should. The "salt" in ???-CTR steram ciphers is actually the IV/NONCE used to generate the XOR-stream. As indicated by the name (NONCE = Number used once), it should be unique and have a reasonable amount of entropy.

In a stream-cipher there are no messages. That means that the NONCE is theoretically unique per session / connection. But if that connection stays alive for a longer period of time (say several hours) and/or larger amounts of data are transferred with the same NONCE (e.g. 100MBs and more) the stream cipher may become suspectible to cryptoanalysis (depending on keysize, entropy of the NONCE and the Cipher algorithm in use).
Most SSL-like protocols (including the TLS standard) suggest to regenerate the NONCE every X minutes or every Y bytes transferred.

Here is an example that i would consider secure enought for sensitive data:

- AES-192 or AES-256 CTR
- NONCE genreated using a CSPRNG (see FIPS-140) with high-entropy seed (e.g. /dev/random)
- Same goes for the Key-Exchange random numbers
- Every 2 hours or every 200MB exchange a new key and a new NONCE.

Practically, you will have to choose these parameters yourself if you are not relying on a standard TLS connection.

---

openssl rand_bytes() does suffice for generating NONCEs.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It looks like openssl RAND_bytes is CSPRNG if /dev/random is available and is still pretty good if using /dev/urandom.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry for not covering the question about openssl. You are right, it is indeed a good CSPRNG.